# Open JQuery accordion when link with an id of element within the accordion is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is my issue http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/12/

As you can see the 4 buttons at the top link to elements within section 1 of the accordion. However when the accordion is closed these links do not work.

I need it so that when you click the links, the accordion opens and the page scrolls to the relevant section, and I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks so much!

My HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - No auto height</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div><a href="#btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">One</a></div>
      <div><a href="#btn2" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Two</a></div>
      <div><a href="#btn3" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Three</a></div>
      <div><a href="#btn4" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Four</a></div>
    </div>


<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <h3 id="btn1">One</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    <h3 id="btn2">Two</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    <h3 id="btn3">Three</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    <h3 id="btn4">Four</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My jquery:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: false,
      collapsible: true 
    });
  });
```

Comment: I appear to have gotten it working with 1 button: 

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/16/

Comment: Got it! :D 

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/19/

Comment: Avoid ansering questions in comments

Comment: @LcSalazar I don't have enough rep to post an actual answer for another 8 hours, otherwise I wouldn't have.

Comment: Ok... Sorry then, my mistake.

Comment: This just opens the accordion, it doesn't take the page to the anchor. Please, take a look at my answer, using a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, so it can work exactly as you want, you will have to use a callback function, so a href is called only when the accordion open finishes.

```
var callback = function() {};  

$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: false,
      collapsible: true,
        activate: function() { callback(); }
    });
  });

    $(".buttons a").click(function(event) {
        var active = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active")+"";
        if(active != "0") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ahref = $(this).attr("href");
            callback = function() {
                location.href = ahref;
                callback = function() { };
            };
            $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 0);
        }
    });
```

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/28/
The answer chosen as the right one does not take the screen where you want. Mine one does.

Comment: @LcSalazar Hey, there is a bug that the buttons don't work if another accordion is already open.

Comment: I'll fix it... just a second

Comment: Yes, just a detail. I changed the if condition from (active == "false" ) to (active != "0"). Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/28/

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event to the buttons that will open the first panel of the accordion, and then scroll to the correct element.

```
$(".buttons a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active",0);
  $(document).scrollTop( $($(e.target).attr("href")).offset().top );
});
```

Preventing the default action and specifically scrolling to the element is needed because activating an accordion panel will trigger a scroll to the top of that panel.

Comment: This just opens the accordion, it doesn't take the page to the anchor. Please, take a look at my answer, using a callback

Comment: updated to take the page to the anchor element inside the panel, instead of just the top of the active panel

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
$(".buttons a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _id=$(this).data("id");
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#btn"+_id).offset().top );  
});
```

and add a data-id attribute to your buttons like this:

```
    <a href="#btn1" data-id="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">One</a>
    <a href="#btn2" data-id="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Two</a>
    <a href="#btn3" data-id="3" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Three</a>
    <a href="#btn4" data-id="4" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Four</a>
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3W5/22/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your solution isn't working well at all, @Shane, because it searches for the `id` before open the accordion. That's why I suggest you to use `preventDefault()` function then open the accordion and then search for the `id`

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as the good one, or at least give me +1 :)