# Open and scroll to accordion section

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a single page site with content placed inside an accordion. I need to both open and scroll to the accordion item when a user clicks on my nav at the top of the page. I found a couple similar functions, this being the closest ([Open JQuery accordion when link with an id of element within the accordion is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016960/open-jquery-accordion-when-link-with-an-id-of-element-within-the-accordion-is-cl)) but unfortunately the jsfiddle links are no longer working.

Right now I just have thecode to get the accordion working...Need to get the scroll to part in there somehow...Thanks!

Code

```js
var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > .toggle-bar');

accordion_head.on('click', function (event) {
    var $a = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if ($a.hasClass('active')) {
        $a.removeClass('active').siblings('.content-wrapper').slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $a.addClass('active').siblings('.content-wrapper').slideDown();
    }
});
```

```css
.accordion li .content-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="accordion">
  <li id="1">
   <a class="toggle-bar" href="#one"><h2>Headline</h2></a>
   

   <div class="content-wrapper">
          
            Content Here
          
            </div>
        </li>
  
        <li id="2">
   <a class="toggle-bar" href="#two"><h2>Headline</h2></a>
   

   <div class="content-wrapper">
          
            Content Here
          
            </div>
        </li>
  
        <li id="3">
   <a class="toggle-bar" href="#three"><h2>Headline</h2></a>
   

   <div class="content-wrapper">
          
            Content Here
          
            </div>
        </li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use scrollTo() from jQuery. An example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Thanks! I'm mainly trying to figure out how to combine the two correctly. As in, open accordion item and scroll to the section.